# Why doesn't Windows let a program called by mod_authnz_external use the network?

Tags: java, c#, windows, apache, mod-auth-external

I need to use Apache (XAMPP) under Windows with mod_authnz_external, which is a module that lets you handle authentication through your own external program. (My use case is pretty complex.) The program receives a line with the username and a line with the password, and returns the result in its exit code: 0 for success, anything else for failure.

The custom-compiled mod_authnz_external has no problem with launching the external auth handler and the solution works well for simple handlers.

However, I need my auth handler to authenticate against an external service. This works well when I run the handler manually (i.e., through `cmd.exe`), but when the handler is invoked by the mod_authnz_external module, it gets all kinds of weird errors.

My first shot at a handler in C# looked like this:

```
class Program {
    static string LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "https://REDACTED";

    static bool CredentialsAreGood(string username, string password) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(LOGIN_ENDPOINT));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        NameValueCollection formData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        formData.Add("username", username);
        formData.Add("password", password);
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formData.ToString());
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        try {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK /* 200 */) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (WebException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (CredentialsAreGood(username, password)) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Access ok for " + username);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        } else {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Access BAD for " + username);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I got when having this C# program invoked by mod_authnz_external occurs in the `WebRequest.Create` method and looks like this:
[image]

Details:
[image]
Stack trace of InnerException:

```
at System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent.CreateWSASocketWithEvent(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, Boolean autoReset, Boolean signaled)
at System.Net.NetworkAddressChangePolled..ctor()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.Initialize()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine.AutoDetector.get_CurrentAutoDetector()
at System.Net.AutoWebProxyScriptEngine..ctor(WebProxy proxy, Boolean useRegistry)
at System.Net.WebProxy.UnsafeUpdateFromRegistry()
at System.Net.WebProxy..ctor(Boolean enableAutoproxy)
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal..ctor(DefaultProxySection section)
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection()
```

I also tried using a similar program in Java and got a different kind of error, also in networking (the host happens to exist):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: REDACTED.REDACTED.com
 at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
 at Authenticate.checkCredentials(Authenticate.java:33)
 at Authenticate.main(Authenticate.java:21)
```

The same also happens when I run the Apache daemon as Administrator. The approach I'm trying works well under Linux, but the target environment is Windows. My current guess is there might be some security feature that's preventing the handler from accessing the network if it's launched by Apache, but it doesn't kick in when I launch the handler manually (both handlers work when I run them myself).

EDIT: Disabling Windows firewall also does not help.

What's causing my handlers to fail when accessing the network? How do I work around it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem is your program is not being allowed through the windows builtin firewall. Add the allow rule and it should work.

Comment: No luck. Neither adding a rule nor completely disabling the firewall helps.